# error 1005 cant create table user.EMPLOYEE and user.STORE (errno 150)

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL and I did everything on my understanding but i can't create the table. says error 1005 can't create table `user.EMPLOYEE` and `user.STORE` (errno 150) help

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMPLOYEE, STORE, REGION;

CREATE TABLE REGION (

    REGION_CODE int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    REGION_DESCRIPT varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (REGION_CODE)
)Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (

        EMP_CODE int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
        EMP_TITLE varchar(4),
        EMP_LNAME varchar(15),
        EMP_FNAME varchar(15),
        EMP_INITIAL varchar(1),
        EMP_DOB date,
        STR_CODE int NOT NULL ,
        PRIMARY KEY (EMP_CODE,STR_CODE),
        FOREIGN key (STR_CODE) REFERENCES STORE(STORE_CODE)

) Engine=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE STORE (

        STORE_CODE int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        STORE_NAME  varchar(20),
        STORE_YRD_SALES numeric,
        REGION_CODE int,
        EMP_CODE int NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (STORE_CODE),
        FOREIGN KEY (REGION_CODE) REFERENCES REGION(REGION_CODE),
        FOREIGN KEY (EMP_CODE) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMP_CODE)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: You may try to move your `foreign key` out of the create statement, as you can see, the `employee` table reference to `store` table, but the `store` table not exists at that moment yet.

Comment: If the tables are going to link to one another and potentially be created after the ones they reference, you may need to disable the foreign key checks before running the create statements.  Don't forget to re-enable them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Error 150 is an invalid key constraint which, if that's the order you're creating tables in, is probably caused by the fact you can't add a constraint in `employee` for the currently-not-existing `store`.

Not being able to create `store` is simply a side effect of that issue since `employee` is not created. Once you fix the problem preventing that, the foreign key restraints in `store` should be okay.

---

The easiest solution is to probably create `employee` *without* the constraint, then add it in later once `store` exists. This would be something like (note the missing constraint in the `EMPLOYEE` table creation):

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    EMP_CODE       int           NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    EMP_TITLE      varchar(4),
    EMP_LNAME      varchar(15),
    EMP_FNAME      varchar(15),
    EMP_INITIAL    varchar(1),
    EMP_DOB        date,
    STR_CODE       int           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY    (EMP_CODE,STR_CODE)
);

CREATE TABLE STORE ( <<no change here>> );

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT EMP2STORE
    FOREIGN KEY (STR_CODE) REFERENCES STORE(STORE_CODE);
```

Comment: Create STORE without the foreign key referencing Employee.
Create EMPLOYEE.
Add foreign key to Store.

Comment: @user2260040, how is that fundamentally different (or better) than the way I suggest (create employee without foreign key, create store, add foreign key to employee)? Both will work with a bi-directional constraint but mine has the (admittedly very minor) advantage that you don't need to change the order of the existing create statements :-)